# Update automatically a specific field in Django model when saving other many-to-many related model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

How can I update a field of a model automatically when saving an instance of a related model?  I need to solve this scenario:

```
class First(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    assigned = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Second(models.Model):
    some_attribute = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    firsts = models.ManyToManyField(First)
```

So, every time I create a Second instance I want to automatically update the 'assigned' attribute for every related object of First model and change it to True.

For simplification I am not saying that I have this models in different apps in the same project, I guess this is not so relevant, I just need the basics of it.

I am trying to override the save method of Second but having trouble to iterate through the related objects:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Second, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
    items = self.firsts
    for item in items:
        item.assigned = True
        item.save()
```

I am also trying to avoid Signals since this sounds like and advance topic and I'm a beginner programmer and I intuit there should be a simpler way to do this. 'First' objects are created in a CreateView for that model; inline formsets are not needed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would help if you'd post your code of overriding the save method, since this is probably the solution. (signals are best avoided)

Comment: Second @Mr.Nun. on sharing the `save()` overriding issue you're having. I'm assuming this is likely just a typo on SO, but just in case: `ManyToManyFields(First)` should be singular `ManyToManyField(First)`

Comment: Honestly, I'm lost with that. What I'm trying surely doesn't make any sense, but I'll edit the question anyway with the save method.

Comment: TYPO corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `save` method of the `Second` model is not the right place to do what you need, because related objects are not yet updated at this time. You should update your `First` model after you save your `Second` model, for instance from the `save` method of the form used to create or update the `Second` instance.

In the `Second` model:

```
def update_firsts(self):
    items = self.firsts.all()
    for item in items:
        item.assigned = True
        item.save()
```

In the form:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super(SecondForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    instance.update_firsts()
    return instance
```

Comment: I've got an error "'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable". It needed a '.all()' in update_firsts, like 'items=self.firsts.all()'. Thank you !

Comment: @naccode OK I updated my answer. If it solved your problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can update all at once:

```
def update_firsts(self):
    self.firsts.all().update(assigned=True)
```